# How to use Windows SDK in Qt 5.7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, bluetooth, qnx

I have been trying to use the Windows SDK inside QT creator with QT 5.7.

I'm trying to use the Bluetooth LE API-s, which are not supported in QT.

I have also installed Visual Studio 2015 for the headers and libs for Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.h

I added to the .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\winrt"
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib"
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib"
```

but now when I try to build I get 8000 issues, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\winrt\Windows.Foundation.h:9149: error: use of enum 'PropertyType' without previous declaration
         typedef enum PropertyType PropertyType;
                      ^
```

I tried to install qt addon for visual studio 2015 but it did not show up..

How to get Microsoft SDK working with QT?

Comment: Can you find out where the `enum PropertyType` is defined? It is either in some other .h file, which you then apparently need to include yourself (that's funny API design from Microsoft, though), or a wrong .h file with same name gets included for some reason in your build (and doesn't have that enum), or then you need to add some `#define` to enable the enum (again funny API design, or at least lazy .h file implementation, to not get a better error message...).

Comment: You can use Microsoft's BLE stack directly from Qt by getting an up-to-date version from git. Works for me just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed QT with miniGW compiler, but I needed to use the MSVC compiler to make the errors disappear.

Comment: It's okay to [accept] your own answer if it solved your issue.